# Overuse of redefining primitive data types?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, coding-style

My current project code base has every unit and its friend refined.

Extract :-

```
...
typedef int m; // meter
typedef int htz;
typedef int s; // second
...
```

Good or Bad?
I hate it! Its a pain, there is no benefit, and "m" globally defined, omg!

But I want to state the reason why I hate it, in a bit more of technical/articulate manor... hello readers!

Can people list For/Against arguments for this pattern?  Many thanks.

Comment: Wow. The guy who wrote the code truly went out of his way to make all variable names sound "natural".

Comment: That's absolutely shocking. Should be `Hz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to make them custom types, as then you can control conversions and overload operators. Right now, I can do meaningless things like multiply a metre by a hertz. Ideally, m / s would yield a velocity- but it won't. It's meaningless to just `typedef` them like that.

Comment: Yes, make them classes, or as @PlasmaHH states, use Boost.

Comment: "I can do meaningless things like multiply a metre by a hertz" - bad example, you get the velocity of a wave (in `m/s`) by multiplying its wavelength (in `m`) and frequency (in `Hz`).

Comment: @Ian: These typedefs don't stop you *adding* a `m` and a `Hz`, which a proper units/dimensions library would. That addition is almost certainly meaningless -- it has no physical meaning at any rate. You could use it in a hashcode of something that has a size and frequency, which is meaningful in a way, but if the units are going to do any good, really you *want* to be forced to cast to a dimensionless arithmetic type before doing a physically meaningless operation.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably they are trying to document intent, but without type safety there is no enforcing it.  It is just clutter that increases the barrier of entry for reasoning about the code.

Even if they did try and create type safety, trying to abstract data at low levels just adds complexity.  It doesn't make solving problems easier.  The variable name describes the contents well enough anyway.

Comment: "variable name describes the contents well enough anyway"... wweelll, should do!

Comment: @IanVaughan Obviously I am optimistic in my pessimism.